# regex - matching non-necessarily consecutive occurrences

Tags: regex, unix, grep

I have been trying to match the occurrences of 0s between the range 3 to 5

So my goal is to match all strings that contain 3 to 5 0s.

So far I have,

```
egrep '[0]{3,5}' *.txt
```

> > expected output

20001         [valid]

200134        [invalid]

20103040      [valid]

203004038002  [invalid]

but this would output strings that only have the consecutive zeroes.

How can I modify the code so that it would also match for non-necessarily consecutive zeroes?

Comment: Try `(0[1-9]*){3,5}`

Comment: @V Anon I've edited my answer. Could you read it again, please?

Comment: Do you really want to match `all strings` or just integers or just numbers? Full line or full word or something else? Output the matching line or the matching string or something else?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The regex you're looking for is:

`^(?!(?:.*?0){6,})(?=(?:.*?0){3,})[0-9]+$`

**Input file:**

```
cat file.txt
20001
200134
20103040
203004038002
```

**Command:**

To use the regex I use `grep -P`, because the lookaround notation `(?!` is not supported in `egrep`

```
grep -P '^(?!(?:.*?0){6,})(?=(?:.*?0){3,})[0-9]+$' file.txt
20001
20103040
```

**Explanation:** First I use a negative lookahead to make sure you can't type more than six characters of `0` anywhere in the string. After that I use a positive lookahead to make sure that the string must contain at least 3 characters of `0`.

The `^` is the start of the string. And the `$` is the end of the string.

Answer (score 1):

I came up with this solution which would allow you to check for 3-5 0s possibly surrounded by anything that isn't a 0 or a space. Hope this helps :)

```
\b(?:[^0\s]*?0[^0\s]*?){3,5}\b
```

If you're checking ONLY strings of numbers with no breaks in between or other characters, you could swap the `\b`s for `^` and `$` and remove the \s and make sure it's only numbers:

```
^(?:[1-9]*?0[1-9]*?){3,5}$
```

^ matches the start of the string, and $ matches the end of the string.

Answer (score 0):

**Input file:**

```
cat file.txt
10203
1020304
102030405
10203040506
1020304050607
```

**Command:**

```
egrep '^([^0]*0){3,5}[^0]*$' file.txt
1020304
102030405
10203040506
```

**Explanation:**

```
^                   # beginning of line
    (               # start group
        [^0]*       # 0 or more non zero
        0           # 1 zero
    ){3,5}          # group must appear from 3 to 5 times
    [^0]*           # 0 or more non zero
$                   # end of line
```

Answer (score 0):

An ERE to match integers containing 3-5 0s, if that's what you want, is `^([1-9]*0){3,5}[1-9]*$`, e.g.:

```
$ grep -E '^([1-9]*0){3,5}[1-9]*$' file
20001
20103040
```

The difference between this and [@Toto's answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/56185755/1745001) is that this will just match integers while @Totos will match any characters with `0`s in between, e.g.:

```
$ echo '0 foo 0 bar 0' | grep -E '^([1-9]*0){3,5}[1-9]*$'
$ echo '0 foo 0 bar 0' | grep -E '^([^0]*0){3,5}[^0]*$'
0 foo 0 bar 0
```